# How to compile code that involve sparse array?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile, sparse-arrays

I have the following code

```
Clear[test];
test[i_, hh_, NN_] := Module[{v0, v1, vtmp},
  dim = Length[hh];
  u = ConstantArray[0., NN];
  v0 = SparseArray[i->1.,{dim}];
  v1 = hh.v0;
  u[[1]] = 1.;
  u[[2]] = v1[[i]];
  Do[vtmp = 2 hh.v1 - v0; u[[k]] = vtmp[[i]]; v0 = v1; 
   v1 = vtmp;, {k, 3, NN}]; u]
```

Now hh is a sparse matrix

```
hh = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 2}] -> 0.1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 0.1}, {1000, 1000}]/0.201;
```

and this is timing by varying `NN`

```
Table[test[1, hh, 10^i]; // AbsoluteTiming, {i, 1, 5}]
(*{{0.000357558, Null}, {0.00196176, Null}, {0.0288201, 
Null}, {0.344731, Null}, {3.32809, Null}}*)
```

Kind of a slow when `NN=100000`. So I need to speed it up.

But Mathematica's `Compile` seems not supporting sparse array, since simple

```
ff = Compile[{{x, _Real, 2}}, x*x];
ff[hh]
```

will lead to error message

> "Argument SparseArray[Automatic,{1000,1000},0.,{<<1>>}] at position 1 should be a rank 2 tensor of "machine-size real number"

So is it possible to compile or any other way to speed up this code?

---

**update**

I just found if I replace `SparseArray[i->1.,{dim}]` with `UnitVector[dim,i]`, then the timing becomes

```
In[8]:= test[1, hh, 10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[8]= {1.96876, Null}
```

much faster but quite odd, why faster?

---

**update2**

even weirder bug behaviour is this.

define

```
comtest = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {NN, _Integer}}, Sin[(\[Pi] n)/(NN + 1)], 
  RuntimeOptions -> "Speed", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]
```

and then run this once

```
comtest[Range[0, 10^5 - 1], 10^5] test[1, hh, 10^5];
```

Now the timing becomes

```
In[10]:= test[1, hh, 10^5]; // AbsoluteTiming

Out[10]= {5.80249, Null}
```

This is ... ridiculous. I tried many times, always this result. I am using mathematica 10.4.

**How could two irrelavent evaluation affect each other??!!!**

Comment: Only packed arrays are admissible in `Compile[]`. But, why not discuss what you're trying to implement here, and we can see if there are better ways to get what you want?

Comment: @J.M. Hi, J.M. The most timing consuming part as you can see is the do loop. `v0` and `v1` are vectors, we can get new vector from `v0` and `v1` by `2 hh.v1 - v0` and extract element at position `i` of it, stored it in List u. and then the v0 is replaced by v1, and v1 by the new vector, and it goes on and on, until we get a whole list of u, so approximately NN iterations

Comment: Okay, but I was asking about the algorithm itself; what are you trying to do with your matrix?

Comment: @J.M. I am implementing this algorithm http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0504627 The most time consuming part is iteration of Multiplication of sparse matrix and vector. Because I know do loop is slow in MMA, so I want to compile it and expecting it should be a few times faster.

Comment: Hmm... try this uncompiled version first: ``test[i_, hh_, NN_] := Module[{dim = Length[hh], ub, v0, v1}, v0 = UnitVector[dim, i]; v1 = hh.v0; ub = Internal`Bag[{1., hh[[i, i]]}]; Do[{v0, v1} = {v1, 2 hh.v1 - v0}; Internal`StuffBag[ub, v1[[i]]], {NN - 2}]; Internal`BagPart[ub, All]]``

Comment: @J.M. Wow, amazing ! Timing is half of before. I am ready to learning something from you : )

Comment: @J.M. So using Internal bag speed up things. The way I update list u slow down the performance, right?

Comment: You can also use so called *Mathematica* linked lists: `test[i_, hh_, NN_] := Module[{dim = Length[hh], ub, v0, v1},  v0 = UnitVector[dim, i]; v1 = hh.v0; ub = {1., hh[[i, i]]};   Do[{v0, v1} = {v1, 2 hh.v1 - v0}; ub = {ub, v1[[i]]}, {NN - 2}];  Flatten@ub  ]`. You can't compile them though.

Comment: @J.M. Hey, I just found this ! The slow performance of my code is not due to my way of updating list u. Why it is because I use `SparseArray[i -> 1., {dim}]`, while you use `UnitVector[dim, i]`. If I change that, my code will be almost the same speed as yours. However, I don't understand, I thought spare vector should perform faster, why it is not?

Comment: @RunnyKine Hi, RunnyKine. Thank you for pointing this out. But I found the real "bug" in my code, see my previous comment

Comment: @matheorem you should definitely add this last finding to your question above and modify the question accordingly.

Comment: @MarcoB I add another interesting finding

Comment: Hmm, you know **not** to use `N` as a variable, no?

Comment: @J.M. I think it is not the problem of `N`, since it already localized. Anyway, if you try to replace 'N' with 'NN', the result is the same.

Comment: @J.M. Hi, J.M. Can you reproduce the bug? I confirm the problem is due to compile, because if I run `Table[Sin[(\[Pi] i)/(10^5 + 1)], {i, Range[0, 10^5 - 1]}] test[1, hh, 10^5]`, then now such problem